# Kotlin Exposed Many-to-Many Jackson Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have done the many-to-many reference in ExposedBD (kotlin) as follows in the wiki:
https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DAO#many-to-many-reference

However, there is a problem of Infinite Recursion (Jackson) when I am trying to return a list of objects in my API (Javalin). 
So, I would like to know how to put the annotation `@jsonIgnore` or if there are other alternative solutions in this case. Here is the mapping:

```kotlin
// many-to-many Actor--StarWarsFilms

// Actor Entity
object Actors: IntIdTable() {
    val firstname = varchar("firstname", 50)
    val lastname = varchar("lastname", 50)
}

class Actor(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<Actor>(Actors)

    var firstname by Actors.firstname
    var lastname by Actors.lastname
}

// StarWarFilm Entity
object StarWarsFilms : IntIdTable() {
  val sequelId = integer("sequel_id").uniqueIndex()
  val name = varchar("name", 50)
  val director = varchar("director", 50)
}

class StarWarsFilm(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
 companion object : IntEntityClass<StarWarsFilm>(StarWarsFilms)

 var sequelId by StarWarsFilms.sequelId 
 var name     by StarWarsFilms.name
 var director by StarWarsFilms.director
 var actors by Actor via StarWarsFilmActors
}

// Intermediate table
object StarWarsFilmActors : Table() {
    val starWarsFilm = reference("starWarsFilm", StarWarsFilms).primaryKey(0)
    val actor = reference("actor", Actors).primaryKey(1)
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to annotate?
There is `use-site` syntaxt in kotlin for annotations : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, I want to use one of strategies found in Java to resolve the Infinite Recursion problem. I want to put @jsonignore annotation in the attribute which is mapped as a FK. In this case, the attribute is "actors" in StarWarsFilm class. I will check the site, however if there are other ways to solve this problem, it will be great.

Comment: Hi @jukabarros did you find a solution?